# How to add Icons in Vaadin grid column?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I am using vaadin 8. I need to show icons on my vaadin grid on a certain column. if the `ID` matches then I icons needs to be shown.

if i do `grid.getColumn("0")` . and if I Log it I get `null`. How can i do it ?

This is what I have

```
class Person{
    private int ID;
    private String name;

    public Person(int ID, String name) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        Grid<Person> personGrid = new Grid<>();

        List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
                new Person(1,"a"),
                new Person(2,"b"),
                new Person(3,"c")
        );


        personGrid.setItems(personList);
        personGrid.addColumn(Person::getID).setCaption("ID");
        personGrid.addColumn(Person::getName).setCaption("name");

        layout.addComponent(personGrid);
```

Comment: What do you expect when doing `grid.getColumn("0")`? there is no column called `0`. you have an `id` column and a `name` column

Answer (score 3):

You can show an Icon in a column by using the ComponentRenderer when adding a column. I like to directly use the short form `grid.addComponentColumn(item -> {return component});`

```
personGrid.addComponentColumn(person -> {
    if(person.getId() == 2){ // use your own matching logic here
        return VaadinIcon.WHATEVER_ICON.create();
    } else {
        return new Span(); // not sure right now if returning null is good idea, so I return Span instead.
    }
).setKey("myIcon"); // set a column key so you can access this column later on using grid.getColumnByKey("myIcon");
```

Edit: I just realized you are asking about Vaadin 8. For Vaadin 8 it is a little different, as VaadinIcons are not Components. Instead you return the Icon strings.
 <sub>V8 is not my strong suit, if this doesnt work i apologise</sub>

```
personGrid.addColumn(person -> {
    if(person.getId() == 2){ // use your own matching logic here
        return VaadinIcons.WHATEVER_ICON.getHtml();
    } else {
        return ""; 
    }, new HtmlRenderer()
).setId("myIcon"); // set column id so you can access the column later on using grid.getColumn("myIcon");
```